# Intermittent issue with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I am using Entity Framework 6.1 version.

I am performing a bulk insert operation with Entity Framework. I am getting an intermittent error with `DbContext`:

> object reference not set to an instance of object" for db context.

Here is my code:

```
public class ApiTimingDataProvider : IApiTimingDataProvider
{
        private ApiTimingDbContext _apiDbContext;

        public ApiTimingDataProvider(ApiTimingDbContext apiDbContext)
        {
            if (apiDbContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("ApiDbContext is Null");

            _apiDbContext = apiDbContext;
        }

        public void InsertApiData(List<ApiTimingModel> apiModelList)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var ctx = _apiDbContext)
                {
                    using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
                    {
                        // some stuff in dbcontext
                        ctx.Database.CommandTimeout = 600;
                        ctx.BulkInsert(apiModelList);

                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                        transactionScope.Complete();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me the reason for getting the exception?

Comment: your code works just once, after that `_apiDbContext` is disposed by the outer `using`. If using `using` you need `new` to renew it every time. However looks like you are dealing with some dbcontext passed in from outside. So you should remove the outer `using`.